# Exchange OWA Group Schedule

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, outlook-web-app

Is it possible to view "Group Schedule" in the exchange web interface (owa)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer - No.
We have to create own form in OWA style.